# Finish awaiting BigQuery query, but reads from table not consistent

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

We are seeing various errors that make it seem like inserts are not yet finished when we read from our tables. For example, we insert 3 days into a date-partitioned table and sometimes we read 2 days in that table.

Could these issues be caused by BigQuery's delayed consistency guarantees? Or is this more than likely some issue in our code?

We are using the Nodejs client for BigQuery. We have executed the insert query in a queryJob and listened for the `complete` event to fire before we read from the table. We have also tried awaiting bigQuery.query and gotten similar results.

One type of insert we perform:

```
const query = `MERGE originalTable USING tempTable...`
const job = await bigQuery.createQueryJob(query)

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    job.on(`complete`, () => resolve())
    job.on(`error`, (error: any) => reject(error))
})
```

Another type of insert:

```
const loadOptions = {
    format: `JSON`,
    schema: schemaObjectToString(tableFields),
    createDisposition: `CREATE_IF_NEEDED`,
}
await bigQueryTable.load(filePath, loadOptions)
```

How we query the table:

```
bigQuery.createQueryStream(`SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT date) as count FROM table`)
```

In the code above, we sometimes a concurrency error of the form: "could not serialize access due to concurrent update" with the MERGE statement. Other times, the MERGE completes fine, but we read incorrect data (e.g. 2 days instead of 3).

Comment: Implication would seem to be you have concurrent modifications to your tables going on.  Are other queries (or load jobs) that modify those tables overlapping the period when the merge is running?

Comment: We don't expect concurrent modifications to be occurring since we update the tables in sequence and await all our functions that modify our tables.

Comment: DId you manage to solve it?